# Eclipse and RED: unable to communicate with XML-RPC server

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, robotframework

Last couple of days, I'm unable to validate any of my custom libraries in Eclipse and RED. I'm using Robot framework and my libraries are writen in Python.

It always ends on this error:

```
RED was unable to find classes/modules inside
'C:\Users\PSaman\Desktop\python\robot_projects\matching\Libraries\MatchingLibrary.py' module
     Unable to communicate with XML-RPC server
```

I'm using Eclipse version:

```
org.eclipse.platform=4.9.0.v20180906-0745
```

and RED version:

```
org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin (0.8.9.201811201254) "RED Robot Editor" [Active]
```

I've tried to:

1) simplify my libraries to even something like:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2   

class MatchingLibrary(object):

    def compare(self):
        self.something = False
```

2) Create a new project.

3) Create a new workspace for my project.

4) Update RED to the latest version.

Yet I get the same error. What would be the solution here?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to replicate your issue with the below setup. However, as the test will execute correctly in Robot Framework I'm convinced this is a RED issue and not a Robot Framework issue. This problem can also be replicated with RED 0.8.8. Thus my recommendation is to create an issue in their [GitHub page](https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues).

My installation is:

- Eclipse Platform     4.9.0.v20180906-1121
- RED - Robot Editor   0.8.9.201811201254
- PyDev for Eclipse    7.0.3.201811082356
- Python 3.7.0

The files I used to verify:

**MatchingLibrary.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    MatchingLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test MatchingLibrary
    MatchingLibrary.Compare
```

and the python library:

**MatchingLibrary.py**

```
import numpy as np 
# import cv2 

class MatchingLibrary(object):

    def compare(self):
        self.something = False
```

Which generates the following error:

> Library specification generation problem
>
> Problem occurred during generating libdoc for 'MatchingLibrary'
>   library located at 'C:\Temp\eclipse\Workspace\MatchingLibrary'. Unable
>   to communicate with XML-RPC server

However, when I run the test it runs successfully as shown in the console output:

```
Command: C:\Users\anne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m robot.run --listener C:\Users\anne\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir6631389808364882183\TestRunnerAgent.py:63395 --argumentfile C:\Users\anne\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir6631389808364882183\args_e04f8d14.arg C:\Temp\eclipse\Workspace\MatchingLibrary
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 3.7.0 on win32)
==============================================================================
MatchingLibrary                                                               
==============================================================================
MatchingLibrary.MatchingLibrary                                               
==============================================================================
Test MatchingLibrary                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MatchingLibrary.MatchingLibrary                                       | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
MatchingLibrary                                                       | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to replicate it. I tried myself again and there is one catch I didn't mention in my initial post. My library in fact looks like this:

**import numpy as np,
import cv2**
...

and this is exactly the problem. From whatever reason, these two imports couldn't be on the top in my library. So if I want to use numpy and cv2, I have to put these two imports into methods where I need them. Then, there is no error and everything works just fine.

Comment: Can you please add this information to your question as it is crucial. In addition I've amended my answer to reflect my new observations.

Comment: I edited my initial post, so others should be able to find an answer here for a similar issue that might occur.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was fixed in RED version 0.8.11, check this [release note](https://github.com/nokia/RED/releases/tag/0.8.11)

Comment: Thank you for sharing that, it'll be much more convenient to use just one import, not many in different methods that need it.

Comment: Downgrade from 0.9.5 to the mentioned version (0.8.11) solved the problem on Win10, thank you for the advice